# deadlock condition arises between child and parent process

Tags: java

From a java program, I want to execute a script which reads an input from a specified folder and generates gcov data. The script generates part of the gcov data correctly, but fails to generate the remaining data until I explicitely terminate my java program, after which it completes its job as expected.

Here is the code that launches the script:

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash CovSeq.sh");
    proc.waitFor();

    System.out.println("Generated gcov Data");          
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Here is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
lines=($(cat path))
mkdir output
mkdir gcovOut
rm -f -r ./gcovOut/*
rm -f -r ./output/*
gcc -g -o temp_exec -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage ${lines[0]}
path1=`pwd`
cd ${lines[1]}
for i in `ls *`
do
cd $path1
./temp_exec < ${lines[1]}/$i > ./output/$i
gcov -b -c ${lines[0]}
mkdir ./gcovOut/$i
mv *.gcov ./gcovOut/$i
mv *.gcda ./gcovOut/$i
cd ${lines[1]}
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that the script is blocked because the parent process does not consume its output. This is known behaviour for `Runtime.exec()`. [Here is an example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419192/java/java/Runtime-getRuntime-exec-String-command) how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn a child process from Java, you *must* consume its standard output *and* standard descriptors, or the child process will block because these files are full.

There are are a couple of ways to do this. Within the script, you can direct all output to a file. Alternatively, you can alter the shell command to direct all output from the script to a file. Either of these approaches make it so that there is no output that needs to be consumed, thus, no blocking.

If you would rather handle this problem from the Java side, you can spawn threads to read the `InputStream` objects that represent the child's standard output and standard error streams. You can discard, log, or interpret these data in your Java program as needed.

Comment: i am already redirecting my output but after generating some gcov files it got blocked, then it resume generation of files only when i explicitly terminate parent process

Comment: @ankur Are you really redirecting the output? How? None of the code you posted shows this happening.

Comment: i am redirecting in my script, bufferreader is the solution ,problem solved...thanks

Comment: @ankur If `BufferedReader` is the "solution", that proves that you are not redirecting *all* of your output (`BufferedReader` would have nothing to read if you were). It's not that you are using a `BufferedReader`, it's that you are now consuming the output of your script so that it doesn't block.